# Xcode 5.1: New non-public APIs issue during validation of app

Tags: xcode, validation, app-store-connect

I upgraded to Xtools 5.1, rebuilt my app, and now I am getting the dreaded non-public APIs error during validation for the app store. I really don't think I've added anything new that could cause this. I don't know if this is related to Xcode 5.1, but the timing is suggesting that.

It's saying that I have these nonpublic APIs in my Payload/appname.app:

```
objc_retainedObject

objc_unretainedObject

objc_unretainedPointer
```

Which I can't find in my source code anywhere.
Is this an Apple iTunesConnect glitch? I have other targets in this project that are not generating these errors.

Comment: I'm seeing the same, this is madness.

Comment: Apple DTS acknowledges that they are getting some reports of this in Xcode 5.1. I'll post an answer if they give me a workaround.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew Smith, please add an answer once you hear an official word.

Comment: Minor update, not only did 5.1.1 xcode not help, but now it's making validation reject an app with a false error saying that it is missing a -568h png file, which it's not. So one step backwards.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out what is triggering this, and the way to fix it:  It seems that verification in Xcode 5.1 only gives these errors if your Deployment Target is set to 5.1.1.  I found that if I change it to 6.0 or later it'll submit just fine.  If I change it back to 5.1.1 I'll get the errors again.

So, until Apple fixes this I guess the way to get around it is either use Xcode 5.0.3 or set your Deployment Target to iOS 6.0 or later on Xcode 5.1.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, but it doesn't really help me as I need to keep the 5.1.1 target in my app.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the only solution I've found is to reinstall Xcode 5.0.2 and submit with that.  This seems to be a bug in 5.1.

-Brian

Answer (score 0):

Apple apparently has patched things on their end, using the same 5.1 version of Xcode from before, I can now submit my app with no errors.

But now I tried Xcode 5.1.1, and I get new errors. So my advice is to stay with Xcode 5.1.